# WPF+Caliburn.Micro: ComboBox and ListBox not updating with dictionary properly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn.micro to make a GUI for a regular expressions library, and for the most part it works. 
But when you try to load new dictionaries or regex patterns, an unhandled exception will be thrown and the program crashes.

In my shell view XAML, here is the ListBox bound to a dictionary that enumerates  key value pairs.

```
<Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
            <TextBlock>Selected Pattern</TextBlock>
        </Label>
        <TextBox Name="RegexSelectionPattern"  IsReadOnly="True" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseDoubleClick] = [Action CopySelectedPatternToClipboard()]"  DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="White" Width="222" Height="40" Margin="0,0,4,0" ToolTip="Double click to copy to clipboard">
        </TextBox>
        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <TextBlock>Dictionary Selection</TextBlock>
        </Label>
        <ComboBox x:Name="Dictionaries"  SelectedValue="{Binding ActiveRegexLibrary}" IsEditable="False" Margin="0,0,4,0" SelectedValuePath="Value"  DisplayMemberPath="Key" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        </ComboBox>
        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <TextBlock>Pattern Selection</TextBlock>
        </Label>
        <ListBox x:Name="RegexChooser" SelectedItem="{Binding RegexSelection}" Margin="0,0,4,0"  SelectedValuePath="Value"  DisplayMemberPath="Key" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        </ListBox>
```

[image: ShellView]
This yields the three controls on the bottom left, two of which are item listers.

In the ShellViewModel, `RegexChooser` is being bound as a Dictionary, which`ActiveRegexLibrary` supplies. The problem is

```
    /// <summary>
    ///  List of choosable regex patterns
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<string, string> RegexChooser
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ActiveRegexLibrary.dictionary;
        }
    }
```

Problems start happening when I use the method to add more patterns to that dictionary. (Or when I try to add new dictionaries to the ComboBox above.) When trying to scroll down to view the newest problem, the program ends in the following exception.

```
       Message=Information for developers (use Text Visualizer to read this):
This exception was thrown because the generator for control 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox Items.Count:38' with name 'RegexChooser' has received sequence of CollectionChanged events that do not agree with the current state of the Items collection.  The following differences were detected:
  Accumulated count 37 is different from actual count 38.  [Accumulated count is (Count at last Reset + #Adds - #Removes since last Reset).]

One or more of the following sources may have raised the wrong events:
     System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator
      System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection
       MS.Internal.Data.EnumerableCollectionView
        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
(The starred sources are considered more likely to be the cause of the problem.)

The most common causes are (a) changing the collection or its Count without raising a corresponding event, and (b) raising an event with an incorrect index or item parameter.

The exception's stack trace describes how the inconsistencies were detected, not how they occurred.  To get a more timely exception, set the attached property 'PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel' on the generator to value 'High' and rerun the scenario.  One way to do this is to run a command similar to the following:
   System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.SetTraceLevel(myItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator, System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceLevel.High)
from the Immediate window.  This causes the detection logic to run after every CollectionChanged event, so it will slow down the application.
```

I notice that a band aid way of fixing this is to switch ActiveRegexLibrary with a dummy object, and then switch it back, and the ListBox displays the new pattern fine. Also, switching to another dictionary in the ComboBox, then switching back to reload the ListView. 
What is the best way to programmatically refresh these item lists?
Putting

```
NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => RegexChooser);
NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ActiveRegexLibrary);
```

in the setters as usually done for non-list properties in Caliburn doesn't seem to work here, and because I'm using Caliburn, I figured I shouldn't directly touch the view with the VM.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are going to see this answer but here I go.

Instead  on using this:

> ```
> public Dictionary<string, string> RegexChooser
> {
>     get
>     {
>         return this.ActiveRegexLibrary.dictionary;
>     }
> }
> ```

Try to use BindableCollection, like this:

```
public BindableCollection<KeyValuePair<String, String>> RegexChooser
{
    get { return this.ActiveRegexLibrary.dictionary; }
}
```